# Mailsender works well when run manually vs. uses nonactual data when timetriggered

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

guys,

simple mailsender, based on value in cell (0=send mail, 1=do not send mail), + some variables to fill the mail.

0 and 1 depends on users behavior, so it may change every day.

When i run this manually, everything works great. When run with time trigger (set on everyday between 8-9:00 am), for some reason, it uses one day old data.

Need to mention, that im complete noob, doing this just for fun and what i usually do is, that i take someones script, change it a bit and use.

Thank you!

```
function alertMail() {
 // fetch variables
 var aktivniDenRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Aktivita_log_mail").getRange("C2"); 
 var aktivniDen = aktivniDenRange.getValue();
 var gifDownloadRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Aktivita_log_mail").getRange("G2"); 
 var gifDownload = gifDownloadRange.getValue();
 var jmenoPrijmeniRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Aktivita_log_mail").getRange("D2"); 
 var jmenoPrijmeni = jmenoPrijmeniRange.getValue();
 var denTydnuRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Aktivita_log_mail").getRange("H2"); 
 var denTydnu = denTydnuRange.getValue();
   // Check if
if (aktivniDen < 1){
// Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Aktivita_log_mail").getRange("E2");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();

// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'Ahoj, ' + jmenoPrijmeni + ', nezapomněl/a sis zapsat včerejší aktivitu? Díky, A.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ' + gifDownload; // Second column
var subject = denTydnu + ' - Neaktivní den';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

When you run from a trigger it runs from the server and does not open the user interface for the spreadsheet like a user can.  So you need to openById().  Also since all of your data is neatly in a row it's much quicker to [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) all at one time and access them from a single array.

```
function alertMail() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet Id');
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Aktivita_log_mail');
  var rg=sh.getRange("C2:H2");
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var aktivniDen=vA[0][0];
  var gifDownload=vA[0][4];
  var jmenoPrijmeni=vA[0][1];
  var denTydnu=vA[0][5];
  var emailAddress=vA[0][2];
  if (aktivniDen < 1){
    var message = 'Ahoj, ' + jmenoPrijmeni + ', nezapomněl/a sis zapsat včerejší aktivitu? Díky, A.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ' + gifDownload; // Second column
    var subject = denTydnu + ' - Neaktivní den';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Cooper, thanks for your reply, tried this solution, but still the same mistake :/

Comment: Could you could share your sheet? Removing any personal information, or an example of it.

Comment: So how does aktivniDen get set? That’s not shown in your example.

Comment: Here it is (made sample spreadsheet, but formulas are completely the same): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jh4JD11iwX1d9RZa2Y8UcOSBFtQ_PFeRIx_t386lMIE/edit?usp=sharing , problem sheet is called "Aktivita_log_mail"

Comment: A2 is `=TODAY()-1` I think your problem is in your cell functions. I'd eliminate them and just go get the data in script.   But honestly I don't want to figure it out.  I avoid cell functions.

Answer (score 0):

Cooper, thanks a lot for your help! Took some time to figure out, where the problem is (as i hadnt much time lately to pay attention to this issue) , but i think i got it.

Im not pretty sure, which one of these steps is really necessary and which one is not, but combination of these should do:

1. Change the time zone of your spreadsheet to your local time zone in settings of spreadsheet - im in GMT +01:00, but (dont know why) time zone of my spreadsheet was set to GMT -08:00. Mailsender trigger was set to 8:00 AM (GMT -01:00), so spreadsheet was still on "yesterday".
2. In settings of spreadsheet, set recalculation of formulas NOW, TODAY, RAND a RANDBETWEEN to when change is made and every hour. I think, combination of point 1. and 2. should be enough...
3. For sure, i set script with trigger (which fires everyday, an hour or two before the mailsender script), that clears and fills important cells with formulas (the same formulas, but it should force sheet to recalculate as if it was opened manually by user), in combination with flush method ( SpreadsheetApp.flush()).

// This is probably needed because the formulas with today() function don't update daily.

```
function resetCells() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1p6oUNo3x6kGcFbpcKOn93uA5K9F1CD8JC1YG4X8EH84');
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Aktivita_log_mail');
  sh.getRange('A2:C2').clearContent();
    sh.getRange('F2:G2').clearContent();
var cell = sh.getRange("A2");
cell.setFormula("=today()-1");
  var cell2 = sh.getRange("B2");
cell2.setFormula("=iferror(filter(Aktivita_log!A:A;Aktivita_log!A:A=A2);0)");
  var cell3 = sh.getRange("C2");
cell3.setFormula("=ifna(ifs(A2=B2;1;J2>=I2;1;H2=H3;1);0)");
  var cell4 = sh.getRange("F2");
cell4.setFormula("=A2-EOMONTH(A2;-1)");
  var cell5 = sh.getRange("G2");
cell5.setFormula("=filter(B4:B34;A4:A34=F2)");
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
```